# Almost sure bounded imply finite expectation?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that the random variable $X$ is $\mid X \mid<M$ almost surely, for some constant $M<\infty.$ Then can we say that $E(X)<C$ for some constant $C<\infty$?

If the expectation is not bounded, is there any additional (other than bounded a.s.) conditions on $X$ that would give us a finite expectation?

My confusion is there could be $0\cdot \infty$ terms where the random variable is infinite with probability $0$. And these terms are not defined well. I believe [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790106/does-finite-expectation-imply-bounded-random-variable) disproves the converse. This is not homework just self studying. Thank you.

Comment: Just for the sake of nitpicking: is $X$ non-negative? Otherwise, you may need absolute values around $X$ in your assumption of upper bounded a.s.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks, Edited as you suggested.

Comment: In measure theory, the $0 \cdot \infty$ terms are zero by convention.

Comment: @fourierwho Thanks, does that mean the statement is correct?

Answer (score 8):

The definition of almost-sure boundedness, or essential boundedness is the following (see also [this definition](http://www.mathresources.com/products/mathresource/maa/essentially_bounded.html)):

$Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})\to \mathbb{R}$ is an *essentially bounded* random variable if there is a $M\geq 0$ so that $\mathrm{P}[|X|>M]=0$, i.e., the set $\{\omega: |X(\omega)|>M\}$ has measure zero.

*Remark* An essentially bounded function is not necessarily bounded. You can find relevant examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum#Examples).

A very easy way to give an affirmative answer to your question is the following: Let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})\to [0,+\infty)$ be a finite-valued non-negative *continuous* random variable. In this case we may use the following representation of the expectation (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values)):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{P}[X\geq x]\mathrm{d}x,$$

where $f(x) = \mathrm{P}[X\geq x]$ has finite support because there is $M>0$ so that $\mathrm{P}[X\geq x]=0$ for all $x>M$ because of our hypothesis that $X$ is non-negative and essentially bounded (almost-surely bounded). As a result, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ will be finite.

We also have the following result (without assuming continuity):

Let $X\in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$ and $Z\in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$. Then, $XZ$ is measurable and $XZ$ is integrable and

$$
\|XZ\|_1 \leq \|X\|_{\infty}\|Z\|_{1},
$$

take $Z=1$ and we get

$$
\|X\|_1 \equiv \mathbb{E}[|X|] \leq \|X\|_{\infty} < \infty,
$$

Therefore $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ is finite, but by Jensen's inequality

$$
|\mathbb{E}[X]| \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|],
$$

so, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is also finite. As a result, essentially bounded random variables have finite expectation.

With some little abuse of notation we can write

$$
\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P}) \subseteq \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})
$$

In general, we can also show that

$$
\mathcal{L}^{p}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P}) \subseteq \mathcal{L}^{p'}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P}), \text{ whenever } p' \leq p,
$$

but the converse is not true. A random variable with finite expectation does not have finite second moment. A random variable with all moments up to $p>1$ may not have finite moments of order $p'>p$ and, further, may not be essentially bounded.

**A necessary clarification:** 
A typical example of an essentially bounded function that is not bounded is the following:
[image]
This is given by (here $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$)
$$
X(\omega)=\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if} x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N},\\
x, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Indeed, notice that $\mathrm{P}[X>1]=0$.

The notion you mentioned in your comment below is not essential boundedness: for $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ the property $\mathrm{P}[X=\infty]=0$ (equivalently $\mathrm{P}[X<\infty]=1$) is that $X$ is **almost-everywhere finite** or **almost-surely finite-valued**. No way, should this be confused with essential boundedness. Take for instance the following very simple function

$$
X(\omega) = \omega,
$$

where $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. Notice that $\{\omega, X(\omega) = +\infty\}=\varnothing$, but $X$ is not essentially bounded and is not bounded.

If a random variable is almost-everywhere finite, it does not necessarily have finite expectation. Take for instance the counterexample provided in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239301/8357). Another example, if you prefer an example not in discrete space, is the Pareto distribution with parameter $\alpha=1$. There are numerous other examples.

Comment: Almost surely bounded, or, essentially bounded, means that there is a $M$ so that $\mathrm{P}[|X|>M]=0$. For instance the function $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is not an integer and $f(n)=n$ for n: integer is essentially bounded (wrt Lebesgue measure), but not surely bounded and it is always finite-valued (in contrast to extended-real-valued functions which may take the value $+\infty$). Continuity is used only in the first part of the answer - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why you excluded infinity as $[0,+\infty)$. Doesn't this mean you have taken that the random variable is sure bounded. In my case I only have that $X=+\infty$ with zero probability. What do you mean by continuous random variable, is it in the sense take values in a continuous range? Also how is continuity and non-negativity used here? Finally does this mean the statement is valid only in some special cases and that it is not valid in general? Can you please give a counter example? Apologies, had to make a change so this comment should proceed your comment.

Comment: The way you have stated your questions, $X$ is almost surely bounded. This does not mean that it is finite-valued with probability one. If $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$ and $\mathrm{P}[X=\infty]=0$, then this doesn't mean that $X$ is essentially bounded and the expectation may be infinite. Would you like me to give a counterexample?

Comment: What I meant by almost surely bounded is $P[\mid X\mid < \infty]=1$, which I belive is equal to $P[\mid X\mid = \infty]=0.$ So as I understand almost sure bounded and this condition are not the same? Could you please explain how they are different? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, these two are not the same. I'll update my answer in a while with a figure.